# Measuring Helix Angle

Tags: gears, measurements, power, manufacturing-engineering

What is the best way to measure the helix angle of a helical cut gear? I have a sun gear from a planetary set that I would like to have custom made but I'm not sure the best way to get the helix angle, the rest of the information I can measure by myself but this one is proving to be a bit more difficult. Does anyone have a tried and true method to measure this?